# Calculate a specific surface integral

Tags: surface-integrals

We have the parametric surface defined by

$x=\dfrac{1}{2}\big(1+b+(1-b)\color{red}{\cos(t)}\big)$

$y=\dfrac{-1}{2}(1-b)\sin(t)$

$z=2b$

with $b\in [1/2,1]$ and $t\in[-\pi,0]$.

- Write $z=u(x,y)$ in order to calculate $u_x$ and $u_{xx}$.
- Find the expression to calculate the surface integral of $u$ over its domain (it is not necessary to calcute its value).

Comment: So where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have to try to find $z=u(x,y)$ but I can't. Maybe it is easy, but I can't see. With this, I can calculate the partial derivates or $u$ and the integral. So, I only need $z=u(x,y)$.

Comment: @MathLover or it is possible to calculate $u_x$ and $u_{xx}$ without calculate $z=u(x,y) explicitly?

Comment: @MathLover I'm sorry, I wrote $\sin$ in both terms, and with that you are right. But in my original question I have one $\sin$ and one $\cos$. I edited in red my original question.

Comment: Yes, if we cut the surface with a plane parallel to the XY plane appears a circle, but its radius changes for different $z$. With that information I must can define $z=u(x,y)$? Really, I can't see it.

Comment: Yes you are correct. We need to use $z = 2b$ to parametrize as $z = u(x, y)$

Comment: Let me check on it in sometime and come back. It does not look straightforward unless I am missing something as well.

Comment: OK if you expand it, it does simplify. I just tried.

Comment: Expand $(x - \frac{1+b}{2})^2 + y^2 = (\frac{1-b}{2})^2$

Comment: Thanks!!  You are right, with that I think I can follow. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: And I think you get $z = \frac{2(x^2+y^2-x)}{x-1}$

Comment: Thanks @MathLover, with your help I solve my question

Comment: Good to hear and you are welcome!